# Is there a way to count the number of products that have a title but no price?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to count the number of products that have a title but do not have a price, the database is a database full of products from a store and there are thousands of products in the database, I am trying to count all of the items that have a product title but also does not state the product price

If anyone understands this then any help would be appreciated

Comment: You mean something like: `db.products.find( { price: null } , { title: { $exists: true }}  )`

Comment: Doesn't work, thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using $exists in mongo query, a query sample is shown below:

```
db.getCollection('your_products_collection').find({'product_title': { $exists: true}, 'product_price' : {$exists : false}}).count()
```

Replace your collection names and column names in the above query

Comment: It was my pleasure